# Unable to mirror display on Alienware m15 r7 running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, display, alienware

I've recently switched from Pop OS! to Ubuntu.  I have no gripes with this new OS, except for the fact that I am unable to mirror my screen when connecting via HMDI or USB-C.  I can use the dual monitor feature just fine, but for some reason, whenever I hit the Mirror tab in the Display Settings, the settings app ends up crashing.  I didn't have this problem with Pop OS!, so I'm thinking this is some incorrect installation that occurred when migrating to Ubuntu, but I'm unsure of what I would need to reinstall.

To the best of my knowledge, I haven't seen this question asked before.  I'm hoping someone can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Migrating to Ubuntu? Did you not do a brand new install of the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Yeah I did a fresh install LTS install.